# RestSharp: POST request in demo-api.hitbtc.com doesn't work

Tags: c#, restsharp

I want to create a bot for demo-api.hitbtc.com. All GET request works great.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using RestSharp;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string apiKey = "xxx";
        const string secretKey = "xxx";

        var client1 = new RestClient("http://demo-api.hitbtc.com");
        var request1 = new RestRequest("/api/1/trading/new_order", Method.POST);
        request1.AddParameter("nonce", GetNonce().ToString());
        request1.AddParameter("apikey", apiKey);

        string sign1 = CalculateSignature(client1.BuildUri(request1).PathAndQuery, secretKey);
        request1.AddHeader("X-Signature", sign1);

        request1.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request1.AddBody(new
        {
            clientOrderId = "58f32654723a4b60ad6b",
            symbol = "BTCUSD",
            side = "buy",
            quantity = "0.01",
            type = "market",
            timeInForce = "GTC"
        });

        var response1 = client1.Execute(request1);

        Console.WriteLine(response1.Content);
        Console.ReadLine();
}

        private static long GetNonce()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.Ticks * 10 / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond; // use millisecond timestamp or whatever you want
    }

    public static string CalculateSignature(string text, string secretKey)
    {
        using (var hmacsha512 = new HMACSHA512(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey)))
        {
            hmacsha512.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text));
            return string.Concat(hmacsha512.Hash.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")).ToArray()); // minimalistic hex-encoding and lower case
        }
    }
```

But when I want to try POST request, I got this error:

```
{"code":"InvalidContent","message":"Missing apikey parameter"}
```

In hitbtc.com [API Documentation](https://hitbtc.com/api#tradingrestful) has said that: "Each request should include the following parameters: nonce, apikey, signature".
Where is the problem?

Comment: as a minor note you should probably edit out your API key and secret key from your question

Comment: @robert-petz Actually, it's a demo API. And I want to other test it to reach answer quickly.

Comment: have you examined the results of `client1.BuildUri(request1).PathAndQuery` to verify that the URI being hit actually is including the `apikey` when `request1` is configured to use POST?

Comment: @robert-petz I got this: `api/1/trading/new_order` from  `client1.BuildUri(request1).PathAndQuery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears RestSharp removes query string parameters by default when performing POST operations.  To work around this, you will need to tell it that your parameters are intended to be query string parameters:

```
request1.AddQueryParameter("nonce", GetNonce().ToString());
request1.AddQueryParameter("apikey", apiKey);
```

instead of using `reqest1.AddParameter(name, value)`

Comment: Well now Nonce and apikey appears in `client1.BuildUri(request1).PathAndQuery` but still i got this error: `{"code":"NotAuthorized","message":"Wrong signature"}`

Comment: The funny side is when i removing `AddBody` I didn't get any authorization error. But this error appears: `{"code":"InvalidArgument","message":"Fields are not valid: side, quantity"}`

Comment: The reason you are not generating the correct signature unless you remove the body is that according to the HitBTC spec the x-signature value is the lower-case hex representation of hmac-sha512 of concatenated uri *and postData*.  Append the JSON to the end of your request when calling `CalculateSignature` and you will no longer error out.  In addition get rid of the division at the end of your nonce as it is not unique enough with that.  Lastly, that will still throw the fields are not valid error but I think that is an API issue and beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: I am laughing though because the [gist](https://gist.github.com/hitbtc-com/9808530) that they specifically reference for C# is not valid according to their own spec haha

Comment: I have contacted them for this issue. But after 1 week no answer. I should try with real API. I'll send the result here.

Comment: solved, they don't want a JSON formatted body on the request - they want a standard form post body.  [Here is a working gist with all of the above notes answered](https://gist.github.com/rpetz/0d838c657dcf0d745d95878871c997c7).

Comment: Did you run the code? Because still not working. But I should run it on real API. If works I'll submit your answer. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Yes I am running the code in the gist I provided and it is working just fine on my end.  Regardless though, the answer I provided very much answers your original question regarding the missing apikey parameter?

Comment: results from the gist code I provided: `{"ExecutionReport":{"orderId":"N/A","clientOrderId":"58f32654723a4b60ad6b","orderStatus":"rejected","userId":"user_246310","symbol":"BTCUSD","side":"buy","quantity":0,"type":"market","timeInForce":"FOK","lastQuantity":0,"lastPrice":"","leavesQuantity":0,"cumQuantity":0,"averagePrice":"0","execReportType":"rejected","orderRejectReason":"badQuantity"}}`

Comment: I have not enough money to buy BTCUSD. But I bought BCNBTC and it worked. Thank you so much